# Getting a read-only copy of an svn repository

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I found an interesting opensource library in the internet which I want to download. The instruction in their website is:

`You can download the source code from our subversion repository, at: 
https://svn.oursvnurl`

I can click on the link above and browse the code in the web browser. I then tried to check out the repo and get the following:

```
svn co https://svn.oursvnurl
Authentication realm: <https://svn.oursvnurl:443> SVN at blah lab
Password for 'sarkar':
```

Which I obviously don't have. Then I tried to switch to http and find:

```
svn co http://svn.oursvnurl
svn: E175011: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://ssvn.oursvnurl'
svn: E175011: Repository moved temporarily to 'https://svn.oursvnurl'; please relocate
```

Is there anyway to get the repo? I don't want to commit; just a readonly copy will be fine for me.

Comment: can you please comment before silently voting down?

Comment: We really don't have enough info to figure out what the issue is. Since this is an open source project, why not give us the URL for the source and the website for the project? This way, we can at least try it and see what's going on. You may get down voted because 1. You didn't give us enough details, and 2. This is a programming site, and your question ins't about programming. You may have better luck as superuser.

Comment: 1. I wanted to know about the problem in general. That's why I abstracted out the url; it was purposefully done so that I don't give to much specific details while I describe the problem. But if  you need some specific information, why not ask instead of voting down? 2. This is a problem related to SVN a version controlling system of code, there are tonnes of questions on SVN, Git.. on SO; not sure why this particular question suddenly becomes not related to programming. I don't have the knowledge that belongs to superuser (not that you know either), otherwise I would not have posted it here.

Comment: And since you asked now this is the url I tried: https://svn.personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/public/latest/moped

Comment: And the page with the instruction: https://personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/projects/moped.php

Comment: Superuser is http://superuser.com. It's a sister site of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called `svn export` for getting the repo without having any intend to contribute to the original copy (which is more or less read-only version of svn checkout). I successfully downloaded the svn repo by:

```
svn export https://svn.oursvnurl
```

Comment: No, `export` is not the "read-only" version of `svn checkout`, since you have no history or any tie to the server for updates.

Comment: I understand, thats why I wrote 'more or less'. This was just for getting the repo in your system which was what I wanted.

Comment: If they set it up correctly for anonymous users to have read access, you would be able to do a checkout without problems. In other words: contact the owner or host if it does not work without a username or password.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am already in contact with the owners and will let them know about this.

Comment: given that `export` produces an unversioned copy of the repo, it IS arguably "read only" from the perspective of the repository -- updates and commits cannot happen.